# CSS Targeting With Grandparents

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

In this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dragontheory/ffSFm/3/) example, using CSS only, can the `.child` element be targeted/styled when the `.secondChild` element gets the attribute `focused="true"`? Something like:

```
.grandParent [focused="true"] ...?
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="grandParent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent sibling">
        <textarea class="secondChild"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my current CSS:

```
.grandParent {
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
}
.parent {
    padding: 20px;
    background: blue
}
.child {
    padding: 20px;
    background: green;
}
.secondChild {
    padding: 20px;
    background: grey;
}
.sibling {
    padding: 20px;
    background: orange;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: There is no way to do that currently. You'll have to use either JS or change the way your `div`s are laid out. You could place `<div class="child"></div>` immediately after the `textarea` and do `.secondChild:focus + .child {}` to achieve something similar.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick answers. I punted to a JS getElementById solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe You can try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/JTUKC/1/

Sincerely i don't know why these selectors don't work

```
div.grandParent div.parent textarea.secondChild:hover + div.grandParent div.parent div.child {
    background: pink !important;
}
```

Comment: @DRAGON, you can use :focus instead hover.